# It is possible to load C-librairies using JNA (Java Native Access)

Tags: java, c, jna

I've problem loading multiple *C-librairies* using java with *JNA* (Java Native Access). When I try to load two libraries it doesn't work. So my question is: is it's possible to use multiple libraries with *JNA* and if so, how to do it?

I'll explain here my problem in more details. I've two different C-librairies, `lib1.so` and `lib2.so`, and I want to use both of them in my Java program. Here is what I did for the moment :

Here is how I load the libraries:

```java
    //Import
     public interface Lib1 extends Library {
        Lib1 INSTANCE = (Lib1) Native.loadLibrary("lib1.so", Lib1.class);
        void call_function1();
     }

    //Import
     public interface Lib2 extends Library {
        Lib2 INSTANCE = (Lib2) Native.loadLibrary("lib2.so", Lib2.class);
        void call_function2();
     }
```

Here is my main function :

```java
     public class App{
        public static void main( String[] args ){
            System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "ClibFolder"); 
            Lib1.INSTANCE.call_function1();   //This instruction works
            Lib2.INSTANCE.call_function2();   //This instruction failed
        }
     }
```

Here is the error I have :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5688ce4440, pid=49318, tid=0x00007f56a1615700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_162-b12) (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.162-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [lib1.so+0x5440]  nullAssignment+0xfc
```

When I execute the instruction calling the second library, the program get an error with the first library. So I suppose that only the first library is loaded, and when it call the second library, in fact it call the first library. That would explain the segmentation fault and the error from the first library. Moreover each library works when I use only one of them, so I don't think they are the cause of the problem.

I really don't know what to do and I would appreciate some help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is an error inside the C  call_function1, i.e. native null pointer exception (access to uninitialized pointer)

Comment: I don't think the error came from the libraries itself cause I can execute them one at time without any problem. The problem came only when I call one after the other.

Comment: Check the crash dump `[lib1.so+0x5440]  nullAssignment+0xfc` nullAssignment on  of  lib1.so base address + 0x5440

Comment: I finally found the problem. In fact, it  came from the nullAssignement function. In both of the libraries it exist a function named like it but they are not some same, they have different inputs. When call_function2() was suppose to call nullAssignement from its library, `lib2.so`, in reality it called nullAssignement function from `lib1.so` and so that lead to segmentation fault. To solve the problem I changed the name of nullAssignement in `lib2.so` and it is now working well. Thank you for your help.